# Regular expression for reading positive integers with leading zeros

Tags: asp.net, regex, reg-expressionvalidator

I have the following `TextBox` and `RegularExpressionValidator`

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtQuantity" runat="server" MaxLength="7"></asp:TextBox>

<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator1" 
runat="server" ErrorMessage="Enter only positive integer values."
ControlToValidate="txtQuantity" ValidationExpression="^[1-9][0-9]*$"
CssClass="required" Display="Dynamic" />
```

It is reading all the positive integers properly and giving error messages on wrong entries.

But validation is getting failed when a positive integer preceding with a 0 is entered.

**Example:** `"098"`, `"09"` etc

Should I change my regular expression or the logic?

Comment: Your regex wont accept `098` `^[1-9][0-9]*$`..it starts with `[1-9]`

Comment: it speaks for itself `"^[0-9][0-9]*$"`

Comment: @moffeltje I *think* OP doesn't want to accept `0` or empty string. And now after you edit it still accepts `0`, but who knows what OP wants. (BTW, `[0-9][0-9]*` → `[0-9]+`.)

Comment: @captainsac `^0*[1-9][0-9]*$` ought to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can allow zeros with non-zeros and disallow just zeros (or empty string) with

```
^(?!0+$)[0-9]+$
```

See [demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5e(%3f!0%2b%24)%5b0-9%5d%2b%24&i=0098)

**REGEX EXPLANATION**:

- `^` - Start of string (not sure it is necessary, I think the regex is anchored by default, but please check)
- `(?!0+$)` - A negative lookahead that checks if the whole string is not equal to `0` (or `0000`)
- `[0-9]+` - 1 or more digits from 0 to 9 (note that it already does not allow empty string)
- `$` - End of string (same note as for `^`)